# Oblique View Frustum Depth Projection and Clipping (Eric Lengyel)

Tags: opengl, clipping

Trying to understand oblique clipping method i've got some problem with theory. According to [this](http://www.terathon.com/lengyel/Lengyel-Oblique.pdf) article written by Eric Lengyel at the end of 2 chapter we get clipping spaces:

- Near <0,0,1,1>
- Far <0,0,-1,1>
  ...

And it is said that:

> each camera-space plane is
> expressed as a sum or difference of two rows of the projection matrix

THIS moment i can not understand. For example, if it's said that Near plane value is "M4 + M3" (where M4 and M3 are the fourth and third rows of projection matrix), and other values ​​are calculated similarly, then the conclusion follows that projection matrix MUST be Identity (to get <0,0,1,1> result from M4 + M3). But we know that it's different. So, can someone explain, what matrix we use and and what is the connection with the projection matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> THIS moment i can not understand. For example, if it's said that Near plane value is "M4 + M3" (where M4 and M3 are the fourth and third rows of projection matrix), and other values ​​are calculated similarly, then the conclusion follows that projection matrix MUST be Identity (to get <0,0,1,1> result from M4 + M3).

First of all, your logic is very flawed here. To get a vector `c=(0,0,1,1)` out of the sum of two vectors `a+b`, you can find an infinte amount of vectors `a` and `b` fulfilling this, for example `(7,-2pi,0,42) + (-7, 2pi, 1, -41) = (0,0,1,1)`.

However, this is completely besides the point, because you misunderstood crucial parts of that article. The clip planes you specified here are *in clip space* (for the special case that `w = 1`, as explained in the article). If we would want to find the equations for the clip planes *in clip space*, there would be absolutely no need for doing any calculations at all because the clip planes are *defined* in clip space as fixed equations. There is no point in calculating `M4+M3` if we already know it would yield `(0,0,1,1)`.

The whole article talks about efficiently calculating the clip planes *in eye space*. And table 1 of that paper makes this extremely clear:

[image: screenshot of table 1 from the referenced paper: plane equations in clip space and eye space]

Comment: thanks. It seems, i've misunderstood the relationship between these columns. And in this case, could you explain why for example Near value in camera space will be M4 + M3, i'm a little confused about this. Why the meaning is exactly that. Where are such conclusions from?

Comment: It is stated in the paper, "Given an arbitrary projection matrix M, the inverse of Equation (2) can be used to map these planes into camera space. This produces
the remarkably simple formulas listed in Table 1, in which each camera-space plane is expressed as a sum or difference of two rows of the projection matrix [2]. "  Read the referenced article if you need more details, but in the end, it is very simple math.

Comment: thanks, @derhass! it seems i've got it with the help of pen and paper. if we want to get C(cam)=M(t)*C(clip) => Mt * <0,0,1,1>  = <M31 + M41, M32 + M42, M33 + M43, M34 + M44> = M3 + M4